# How to simplify (to shorten) a long sentence with similar patterns?

Tags: ellipsis, parallelism

Suppose that the performance of a system depends on the efficiency of two sub systems called **A** and **B**. And I want to say something along this line:

> **A** can compensate the poor performance of **B**, but **B** can not compensate the poor performance of **A**.

I am wondering how I can simplify this sentence into a more compact one with omitting the unnecessary repetitive (redundant?) parts. I would say:

> **A** can compensate the poor performance of **B**, but not true the other way around.

I am wondering if my sentence is correct and idiomatic? If so, is it good for an academic and sort of formal writing?

Comment: 'But not the other way round'. However the usual expression would be 'but not vice-versa'. https://www.dictionary.com/browse/vice-versa

Comment: It is compensate for in English, in the sense you are using. **A can compensate *for* *B's poor performance, but the inverse is not true**.

Answer (score 0):

Whereas A can compensate the poor performance of B, the opposite is not true.

or

A can compensate the poor performance of B, whereas B cannot reciprocate.

Answer (score 0):

The most direct conversion is this:

> A can compensate the poor performance of B, but B cannot that of A.

This combines two fairly basic concepts: removing a repeated verb (in this case, only the main verb but not the differing modals) in a parallel structure, and replacing a repeated noun with a pronoun.

The other suggestions are valid, and probably a bit easier to parse, but they don’t retain the *exact* same sense as this one does.